# How to point DKMS to kernel headers?

Tags: kernel, dkms

When installing a package that includes a kernel module (in my case, openafs-modules-dkms), package configuration fails because DKMS fails to find modules even though package `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` is already installed.

```
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

Answer (score 8):

DKMS is trying to follow `build` symlink inside the `/lib/modules` (not sure why it's not there), so create it:

```
# ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

This was found by checking the file system calls made by dkms:

```
# strace -f -e trace=file dpkg-reconfigure <package> >/tmp/dkms.log 2>&1
```